# Rails: eager load related model with condition at third model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, eager-loading

I am very stuck on this problem:
I have next models (it's all from Redmine):

1. Issue (has_many :journals)
2. Journal (has_many :details, :class_name => "JournalDetails)
3. JournalDetails

I want fetch last changing of a state of a issue: date saved in Journal model but for filter only changing state I must join to JournalDetails.

```
Issue.eager_load(:journals).eager_load(journals: :details)
```

It's work  but journals have all items not only changes of state - and how I can filter only changing of state without additional query I don't know

My next try:

```
Issue.eager_load({:journals => :details}).where("journal_details.prop_key = 'status_id'")
```

In this case I don't get issues which has not changes of state.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Issue.joins(journals: :details).where(details: { prop_key: "status_id" })
```

Or, you can merge the scope from the details model:

```
class JournalDetails
  scope :for_prop_key, -> (status_id) { where(prop_key: status_id )}
end

Issue.joins(journals: :details).merge(
  JournalDetails.for_prop_key("status_id")
)
```

Comment: First case doesn't work: Issue.include({journals: :details}).where(details: {prop_key: "status_id"})
TypeError: wrong argument type Hash (expected Module)

Comment: You're right, `joins` should be used instead. I corrected the example.

Comment: Yury, I try same case, but it's output nest sql: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "issues"."id") FROM "issues" LEFT OUTER JOIN "journals" ON "journals"."journalized_id" = "issues"."id" AND "journals"."journalized_type" = 'Issue' LEFT OUTER JOIN "journal_details" ON "journal_details"."journal_id" = "journals"."id" WHERE "journal_details"."prop_key" = 'status_id' - condition apply to whole select and remove Issues without changing state.

Comment: I didn't quite understand. What exactly you are trying to achieve with your select? I thought you want to select all issues, which have a journal_details with prop_key equal to "status_id".

Comment: I want fetch not only issues with prop_key equal to "status_id" but all issue and if they have prop_key in journal I want show time for when state was changed.

Comment: So you want all issues, which have a non null prop_key in the journal_details?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all issues, which have a non null prop_key in journal details:

```
class JournalDetails
  scope :with_non_null_prop_key, -> { where("prop_key IS NOT NULL") }
end

Issue.joins(journals: :details).merge(
  JournalDetails.with_non_null_prop_key("status_id")
)
```